# Gaussian blur shrinks zooms image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, convolution, gaussian

I am trying to implement Gaussian blur, I have generated Gaussian filter as per wikipedia:

```
void FilterCreation(double GKernel[][5]) 
{ 
    // intialising standard deviation to 1.0 
    double sigma = 1.0; 
    double r, s = 2.0 * sigma * sigma; 
  
    // sum is for normalization 
    double sum = 0.0; 
  
    // generating 5x5 kernel 
    for (int x = -2; x <= 2; x++) { 
        for (int y = -2; y <= 2; y++) { 
            r = sqrt(x * x + y * y); 
            GKernel[x + 2][y + 2] = (exp(-(r * r) / s)) / (M_PI * s); 
            sum += GKernel[x + 2][y + 2]; 
        } 
    } 
  
    // normalising the Kernel 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) 
            GKernel[i][j] /= sum; 
}
```

If I understood correctly how to convolve the image in Gaussian blur, I take pixel and takes surrounding pixels, multiply each pixel by value of kernel and sum it. e.g:

```
kernel       matrix
1 2 3        1 2 3 4 5  
4 5 6        6 7 8 9 10
7 8 9        11 12 13 14 15
```

If I select pixel (in matrix) with value `7` ( it has indexes (1,1)) convolution would looks like:

```
new_matrix(1,1) = ( 1 * 1 ) + ( 2 * 2 ) + ( 3 * 3 )
              ( 4 * 6 ) + ( 5 * 7 ) + ( 6 * 8 )
              ( 7 * 11 ) + ( 8 * 12 ) + ( 9 * 13 )
```

and do this for every pixel I can (so I can’t take pixels from first or last rows/columns) code I use:

```
void CreateGaussFilter(int kernalHeight, int kernalWidth, double kernalArray[5][5]){

    Mat image = imread("konik.jpg");
  Mat filter(image.size(),CV_8UC1);

    int rows=image.rows;
    int cols=image.cols;


    int verticleImageBound=(kernalHeight-1)/2;
    int horizontalImageBound=(kernalWidth-1)/2;

    for(int row=0+verticleImageBound;row<rows-verticleImageBound;row++){
        for(int col=0+horizontalImageBound;col<cols-horizontalImageBound;col++){

            float value=0.0;

            for(int kRow=0;kRow<kernalHeight;kRow++){
                    for(int kCol=0;kCol<kernalWidth;kCol++){
                        float pixel=image.at<uchar>(kRow+row-verticleImageBound,kCol+col-horizontalImageBound)*kernalArray[kRow][kCol];
                        value+=pixel;
                    }
            }
        filter.at<uchar>(row,col)=cvRound(value);

        }

    }
  imwrite("myFilter.jpg",filter);

}
```

Now, the image I use is:

[image]

and result image is:

[image]

As you can see it shrank the image, ofc I am omitting first and last 2 rows and columns, but it still shouldn’t make such difference... Did I  misunderstand the way how to convolve? Or is there any error in my code? I fail to find any mistakes.

Thanks for help

Comment: probably you are interpreting a 3 channel image as being 1 channel during processing => only 1/3 in x dimension is processed and 3 identical pixels next to each other in a row

Comment: imread by default reads image as 3 channel. Use the right flag to read as-is as or to read as grayscale